# Turn off Lock Screen notifications completely, notifications keeps showing even when disabled

Tags: ipad, notifications, ios

How can i disable completely the notifications from appearing in the lock screen?
I unchecked these options:

[image: accessWhenLocked]

But i'm STILL getting an abstract of every notification in the lockscreen so people who don't have my password can still read my chats and emails.

[image: accessWhenLocked]

This is very annoying, help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is actually quite simple, but you will have to do it individually for each app. First, make sure you have the latest release of iOS 8 (this is not completely necessary, but recommended). Next, go to the Settings app and scroll down until you find the application you want to disable notifications for on the lock screen.

[image: Settings Application Cell]

Now, click that cell and scroll down on the presented screen for "Notifications"

[image: App Settings Screen]

Now, on this screen there is a slide that says "Show in Lock Screen". Disable this (like this):

[image: Disable "Show in Lock Screen]

Now you're finished! Let me know if this does not work for any reason.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue.
It's a pretty awful lock screen configuration...